# Word Vba Userform textbox onChange

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a userform have one textbox field and with ok and cancel button

for myRun macro:

```
Sub myUserForm()
    UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = Selection.Font.Size
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

And for my Form marco:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim myValue As String
    myValue = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
    If Not IsNumeric(myValue) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a number"
        MsgBox myValue
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to ask can it possible to get the value of the previous value when myValue is not numberic

if my Selection text size is 10pt, when I run the form, it show "10" in the textbox1, when I change the textbox field to "text", then I will alert "Please enter a number" and alert "text" can it alert 10?

Comment: You could store it in a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean :

```
Dim myNumber
If Not IsNumeric(myValue) Then
myNumber = InputBox("Enter number:")
MsgBox "Entered " & myNumber
End If
```

Please note that negative numbers are also Numeric.

Comment: You must put Dim myNumber to the Module top section

Comment: when I load the form, the textbox field have a value is "10", then I change it to "text", I want to alert "10" after I onChange the textbox field

Comment: you want to store a global variable: put Dim myNumber at the top section, so it is global.
put this: If Not IsNumeric(myValue) Then myValue = myNumber Else myNumber = myValue after: myValue = userForm1.TextBox1.Value

Comment: you mean Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim myNumber
   If Not IsNumeric(myValue) Then myValue = myNumber Else myNumber = myValue after: myValue = userForm1.TextBox1.Value
    
End Sub

Comment: No. You need to put Dim myNumber at the very first line of the window. If TextBox1_Change is called and reaches End Sub, VBA will erase all variables stored within. That is why you need to put it outside any function. this is called global variable

Comment: haha nice ^^ you could thank me by choosing my answer as the right one :P

Comment: I want to ask one more question, why when I use Dim myNumber as first
if I change the text field to "-2", it will alert previous value, but before IsNumberic  negative numbers are also numberic

Comment: can you try MsgBox IsNumeric(-2) and tell me the outcome ? If it is not true, then this differs from visual basic ;) You should then simply use If IsNumeric(Replace(myValue,"-","")) Then ... instead

Comment: the result is true, because i do it in  onchange, so when I type "-", it will alert previous value, but when I type "2-", it will alert previous value as "2" not "10"